# Why is ggplot failing to run over multiple lines even though my code seems to be correct?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

For some reason ggplot has a hard time running when the code is split into multiple lines. For example this line of code will run (but is long and difficult to work with):

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = weight, y = horsepower)) + geom_point(size = 3) + labs(x = "Vehicle weight (lbs.)", y = "Engine Horsepower") + ggtitle("Weight vs. Horsepower")
```

However, these lines of code, which fit into the tidyverse style guide, will not run:

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = weight, y = horsepower)) + geom_point(size = 3)
+ labs(x = "Vehicle weight (lbs.)", y = "Engine Horsepower")
+ ggtitle("Weight vs. Horsepower")
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and my searches haven't turned up anything.

The error I am getting is:

```
Invalid argument to unary operator calls
```

Comment: Try putting the `+` operator at the end of each previous line.

Comment: Can you give reference where in tidyverse style guide is says OK to put `+` on the newline?

Comment: @PoGibas The styleguide section on "Long Lines" does not seem to mention `+` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the + sign at the end of each line. 
Like

```
ggplot(data,aes(x,y)) +

  geom_line()
```

Not

```
ggplot(data,aes(x,y)) 

 + geom_line()
```

Similarly, you would also need the similar approach when using dplyr pipe (%>%)

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with the layout and structure of your code.

Dont put the `+` operators at the start of each new line.

Instead, you need to put them at the end of each of the previous lines like this:

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = weight, y = horsepower)) +
    geom_point(size = 3) +
    labs(x = "Vehicle weight (lbs.)", y = "Engine Horsepower") +
    ggtitle("Weight vs. Horsepower")
```